# Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name [Bokeh plot from SQL with slider callback]

Tags: python, sql, pandas, plot, bokeh

I'm trying to make an interactive plot with a slider. The plot will show yearly expences in ranked order. The slider would change the year of the data. I suppose I need to utilize Bokeh server.

With panda I run a query from a local MySQL server and get the following kind of table.

```py
         CATEGORY    TOTAL
0             Foo    11.00
1             Bar    51.37
2          Foobar   114.86
```

The code, that almost works..

```py
#SliderTest.py

#Init
year = 2012
query = SqlCmds.R_YearlyTopExpenses(year)
source = pd.read_sql_query(query, con=connection)

# Create plots and widgets
plot = figure(
    y_range=source['CATEGORY'],
    x_axis_label='Amount',
    y_axis_label='Category',
    plot_width=800
    )

plot.hbar(
    y=source['CATEGORY'],
    right=source['TOTAL'],
    left=0,
    height=0.5
    )

slider = Slider(
    start=2012,
    end=2019,
    value=2012,
    step=1,
    title="Year"
    )

# Add callback to widgets
def callback(attr, old, new):
    year = slider.value

    query = SqlCmds.R_YearlyTopExpenses(year)
    new_data = pd.read_sql_query(query, con=connection) #changed
    source.data = new_data #added

slider.on_change('value', callback)

# Arrange plots and widgets in layouts
layout = column(slider, plot)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

I run the following command

```py
bokeh serve --show .\SliderTest.py
```

As a result I get the following, a slider on top of the plot, but the plot does not update with the slider, nor the title.

[image: Slider does not update the plot]

I see that I get a warning inside the callback, saying `source` variable is unused.

How do I get the plot and the title to change according the slider?

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
source = pd.read_sql_query(query, con=connection)
```

inside a function, you are creating a new purely local variable that has relation at all to the `source` defined up above, and then it is promptly thrown away when the function exits (that's the reason for the warning about it not being used). However, even ignoring this, it is not best practice to replace Bokeh `ColumnDataSource` objects wholesale. What you need to be doing instead is updating the existing source:

```
source.data = new_data
```

If you are using Bokeh >= 1.3 then `new_data` can just be a Pandas DataFrame directly. Otherwise there is `ColumnDatatSource.data_from_df(...)` statif method you will have to call on the DataFrame to convert it to the expected format first.

Comment: I had version 1.2 but now it is upgraded to 1.3.1. I also edited the code in the function (see in the initial question as I was not able to format the changes nicely on the comment section). After the edit I get the following error: UserWarning: Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name

Comment: That's a pandas question, not a bokeh question, I am afraid I don't know anything about it.